# How to create a new file by searching specific text in old file

Tags: vbscript, scripting

My OLDFile looks like `FolderList.txt` with the content:

```
\\srv10177\temppahir$\Desktop\WORK\6758\Archive\Article\20140825_123400
\\srv10177\temppahir$\Desktop\WORK\6758\Archive\Article\20140827_065126
\\srv10177\temppahir$\Desktop\WORK\6758\Archive\Article\20141006_094447
\\srv10177\temppahir$\Desktop\WORK\6758\Archive\Article\20141006_110546
\\srv10177\temppahir$\Desktop\WORK\6758\Archive\Article\20141008_105947
\\srv10177\temppahir$\Desktop\WORK\6758\Archive\Article\20150917_093710
\\srv10177\temppahir$\Desktop\WORK\6758\Archive\Article\20151005_190254
\\srv10177\temppahir$\Desktop\WORK\6758\Archive\Article\20151005_191124
```

And I want to create a new file with name `FolderListNew.txt` and the content:

```
\\srv10177\temppahir$\Desktop\WORK\6758\Archive\Article\20141006_110546
\\srv10177\temppahir$\Desktop\WORK\6758\Archive\Article\20141008_105947
\\srv10177\temppahir$\Desktop\WORK\6758\Archive\Article\20150917_093710
\\srv10177\temppahir$\Desktop\WORK\6758\Archive\Article\20151005_190254
```

So basically I want to do a search on 2 text:

```
Text1 = 20141006_110546
Text2 = 20151005_190254
```

and pull the lines from the first occurrence of `Text1` until `Text2` occurs.
Assume data will always be something like this and will be in sorted format ascending as per these timestamp.

I have tried the below script, which doesn't work and is incomplete:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, msg, Filename, file, filestreamOUT, objFile, strContents, strLine, line, Text1, Text2, OLDFilename, tmpStr, MyPos
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Text1 = "20141006_110546"
Text2 = "20151005_190254"
OLDFilename="C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\VB\Folderlist.txt"
WScript.Echo "String to find is : " & Text1
Wscript.Echo "OLDFilename is " & OLDFilename
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(OLDFilename, 1)
Wscript.Echo "Reading file the first time:"
strContents = objFile.ReadAll
Wscript.Echo "Line being read is" & strContents

WScript.Echo "tmpStr.ReadLine is : " & Line
'MyPos = InStr (tmpStr.ReadLine, Text1)
WScript.Echo "MyPos value is : " & MyPos
If MyPos >= 0 Then
  'WScript.Echo "Match NOT Found in File and tmpStr.ReadLine is : " & tmpStr.ReadLine
Else 
  WScript.Echo "string value is : " & strLine
  WScript.Echo "Match Found in File and tmpStr.ReadLine is : " & tmpStr.ReadLine
End If
```

Comment: I am new to vb scripting. I have still tried a few things like..

Comment: I am not able to put the entire script here in a proper format.. I guess this is VB script. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @simonalexander2005  - I am not able to put my script here in a proper format.. Watever I have posted above , is it readable ?

Comment: @varocarbas - This is VB Script. I am trying to learn this thing on my own since a week now but not able to achieve this simple thing till now and the script just starts from here and there is a long way to go from this. So any help wud be great and wud save a lot of time. Thanks !

Comment: OK. Next time make sure that you use the right tag. And remember that VB.NET is a completely different story (e.g., it is a compiled language).

Comment: @varocarbas and simonalexander2005 - Can you please advice on this ? I tried to use the InStr () function and getting values, but not able to achieve what I need here..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put specific lines from one file into another file it's best to read the source file line by line:

```
Set inFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(OLDFilename)
Do Untile inFile.AtEndOfStream
  line = inFile.ReadLine
  ...
Loop
inFile.Close
```

Start writing the output file if the line contains `Text1` and stop writing after it contained `Text2`:

```
Text1 = "20141006_110546"
Text2 = "20151005_190254"

writeOutput = False

Set inFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\input.txt")
Set outFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\output.txt", 2, True)
Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
  line = inFile.ReadLine
  If InStr(line, "20141006_110546") > 0 Then writeOutput = True
  If writeOutput Then outFile.WriteLine line
  If InStr(line, "20151005_190254") > 0 Then Exit Do
Loop
inFile.Close
outFile.Close
```